# Sync AWS snapshots to secondary account - supplier ask for "swap" - security theathre?

Tags: backup

I'm managing an AWS account for a specific purpose for a company of 120 people. Another supplier of this company of around 5 people also has an AWS account.

To protect resources in an AWS account from malicious deletion, it is recommended to synchronise disk snapshots to a secondary account.

The other supplier has approached us to do a swap for this purpose: In their mind we are to store their secondary snapshot copies in our AWS account and they will store our secondary snapshots in their AWS account.

Apart from the commercial considerations - this sounds like security theathre to me? Isn't it just as good to find a second person at each of our organisations who has the login to a separate AWS account and synchronise our snapshots to that. This also resolves issues such as

- if they are supposed to automatically have access to everything we do (or we cannot back it up to another account)
- what happens if their supplier relationship goes sour
- the complexity of contacting the right person, which seems naturally easier within the same company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bad idea to trust the third party supplier if you don not have to.**

Use the principal of [least priviledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Create your secondary account yourself, and lock the account credentials away in your business safe/lawyers office (and not in your operational password safes).

This will give the same backup advantages without the downside of trusting a(nother) third party (other than Amazon).

In general I appreciate the approach you are taking and think it is a cheap backup to avoid an ugly and probably rare problem.